# Python Clipboard Assistent (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, clipboard

I am trying to create a tool that assists me in filling out a specific web form.
For that I have a „.txt“ with the necessary information. Now I am trying to find a python module that detects that I pasted the last content and loads the next content (from txt) into the clipboard. Is that possible with python?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can the `pyperclip` module to copy and paste text to and from the clipboard. You can take a look at http://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html for more info.

They have an example where they copy a string onto a clipboard and paste it.

```
>>> import pyperclip
>>> pyperclip.copy('Hello world!')
>>> pyperclip.paste()
'Hello world!'
```

But of course, I believe you can extract the string from your text file and use it.

Comment: No detection of paste-event (at least not in the documentation)